# How to reach a desired point in the code in java?

Tags: java

I want to make a logic of getting grades. I proceed in a way of getting total marks as input from user using the `Scanner` class, then I'm validating marks if it is between `0` and `100`(both inclusive).

Now if the marks are not in between this range, I print "Enter valid marks!!", and I want it to go to previous step and ask for the input from user again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Performance
{
    public static void main(String[] aa)
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the marks :"); // Line 7
        int marks= scnr.nextInt();
        if(marks<0 || marks>100)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter valid marks!!");
        }
    // Now if this condition is true then I want the control to go again to line 7
    // Please suggest me the way to Proceed
    }
}
```

Please suggest the way to proceed with the modification in the above code.

Comment: Hint: Put it in a while loop, so now you can research on this how to do.

Answer (score 2):

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

You want to do something like that:

```
do {
   code line 1;
   code line 2;
   code line 3;
} while(yourCondition);
```

Now, if `yourCondition` is satisfied, the code will go to `code line 1` again (will perform the code block between `do` and `while`).

Now, after you understand how it works, you can easily apply this to your task.

Comment: This is valid, a `do-while` loop will run at least once, and then loop again if the `while` part remains true. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
boolean b = true;
while(b){

    if(marks<0 || marks>100){
        System.out.println("Enter valid marks!!");
        marks= scnr.nextInt();
     }

     else{
         b= false;
        //Do something
     }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't provide answer to the question

Comment: Why is the `//Do Something` inside the `while`?

Comment: @user93353 Do your calculation inside else block.

Comment: @AchintyaJha - why? why not do it outside the while?

Comment: @user93353 if you do in while loop it will be executed every time when while loop runs. If we do in else it will be executed only when if condition will be false and this is what needed here.

Comment: You are not getting my point - anyway not important.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28586/discussion-between-achintya-jha-and-user93353)

Comment: @user93353 i am also eager to know about what you want to say.........is it some problem in writing some code in else block......although i don't find any problem in that way too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the marks :"); // Line 7
    int marks= scnr.nextInt();
    if(marks<0 || marks>100)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter valid marks!!");
    } else
        break;
} while (true);
```

Comment: thanks Detheroc for the help....:)

Answer (score 0):

```
8     int marks = scnr.nextInt();
9     while(marks<0 || marks>100)
10    {
11        System.out.println("Enter valid marks!!");
12        System.out.println("Enter the marks :");
13        marks = scnr.nextInt();
14    }
```

Comment: Before the line numbers were edited out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for your help.
FInally i proceeded in the way as follows:

```
  public static void main(String[] aaa)
 {

int counter=0;
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int marks;
do
{
    counter++;
    System.out.println("Enter the marks :");

    marks= scnr.nextInt();
    if(marks<0 || marks>100)
    {
        System.out.println("Marks entered are not        valid");
        if(counter>=3)
        {
            System.out.println("You have exceeded the maximum number of attempts!!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Enter valid marks!!");

    }
    else
        break;
} while(true);
 }
```